# Can you let your users to upload video on via Youtube api?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

do you know if youtube or another services let my users (registered to my website) upload videos without the need to have a youtube account?

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload videos anonymously, so they'd need to have a YouTube account in order to upload a video, unless you're somehow authenticating them to let them upload videos on your behalf (assuming you have a YouTube account and want them to upload videos to your channel).